# Проблема с кодировкой в MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Я делаю OpenAPI для своего сайта. На моём сайте есть скрипт, который обращается к БД (MYSQL) на стороннем сайте есть яваскрипт, который обращается к запросу на моём сайте и выводит картинку, описание и заголовок. Если текст на английском, то всё работает нормально. Но если на русском, то на стороннем сайте вместо текста значится null.

Подскажите, как справиться с этой проблемой?

**Добавлено.**

Это станица с запросом.

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    $sql = "SELECT z, pz FROM event LIMIT 2";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rows[] = array(
        "z" => $row['z'],
        "p" => $row['p']);
    }

    $json = json_encode($rows);

    $callback = $_GET['callback'];
    echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
?>
```

Comment: Код в студию :)

Comment: Ну вот, попробуйте перед этим:
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
поставить:
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
или
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251';");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте перед запросом к базе выполнить это:

```
$encode = 'utf8';
mysql_query("SET NAMES '$encode';", $sqlLink);
```

Где $encode - кодировка. Нужно поставить соответствующую кодировке страницы (скрипта).
А $sqlLink - дескриптор подключения к серверу СУБД.

Comment: Спосибо большое. Помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Более правильный способ задать кодировку, это использовать функцию [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php). Правда данная функция требует MySQL 5.0.7 или более поздних версий.

Цитата с той же странички, гласящая, что использование mysql_query для установки кодировки не рекомендуется.

> Using mysql_query() to execute SET NAMES .. is not recommended.